# Optimizing an openCL calculation with bitwise operations

Tags: c, opencl

Let me commence by stating my objective: I am attempting to compare two 13-bit integers: >, <, and =; I have to do this calculation trillions of times, so it is imperative that I optimize it as much as possible.

My program currently utilizes Python 2.7 and pyopencl to achieve this calculation. I am averaging about 800 GFlops out of my ATI Radeon 6870 which is fine for now.

So here is my question: If instead of caring out the <, >, and = operators on 4 byte floats (as I am doing now), I wrote bitwise functions to handle the <, >, and =, and I was able to process 2 - 13 bits objects at a time, would this increase my speed? Or does C already have the most efficient way of finding <, and >, and = (obviously) for floats?

Comment: What do you want to do with the result of the comparison?

Comment: Are the integers signed or unsigned?

Comment: You could vectorize that floats to float4/int4 which compliments HD6870's vliw4 microarchitecture. Maybe pure bitwise uses integer pipeline. Add some  float versions to use fp pipelines too.

Comment: Why are you using floats and not ints or unsigned ints?  The float and int hardware uses  different silicon.  There could be less FPU's  that int units, or the FPU could take more clocks cycles per operation.